# Did not find the image definition file imagedefinitions.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

"Invalid action configuration
Did not find the image definition file imagedefinitions.json in the input artifacts ZIP file. Verify the file is stored in your pipeline's Amazon S3 artifact bucket"

getting this error, i did not user codebuild in AWS and image is directil pushed to ECR , we build that image with maven,
i have uploaded imagedefinitions.json to the artifi bucket , i also zipped that file ,but nothing worked,

can any one suggest anything

Comment: Hey @Akshay , are you using a Deploy stage from CodePipeline? if so, you need to create either: a source s3 action where you have the imagedefinitions file, or a CodeBuild step to create that same file and include it in output artifacts. Here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cd-pipeline.html

Answer (score 22):

When you are using ECR as a source, ECR generates an artifact file called 'imageDetail.json' which is of the format [1]. But the ECS Deploy stage requires a file called 'imagedefinitions.json' which is formatted differently [2].

To provide the required file, please add a CodeBuild step betweenn source and deploy with the following buildspec: (Basically converting the file)

```
version: 0.2
phases:
    install:
        runtime-versions:
            docker: 18
    build:
        commands:
            - apt-get install jq -y
            - ContainerName="todo"
            - ImageURI=$(cat imageDetail.json | jq -r '.ImageURI')
            - printf '[{"name":"CONTAINER_NAME","imageUri":"IMAGE_URI"}]' > imagedefinitions.json
            - sed -i -e "s|CONTAINER_NAME|$ContainerName|g" imagedefinitions.json
            - sed -i -e "s|IMAGE_URI|$ImageURI|g" imagedefinitions.json
            - cat imagedefinitions.json

artifacts:
    files:
        - imagedefinitions.json
```

#### Important1: Update 'ContainerName' as it exists in your task definition

#### Important2: Make sure input artifact of deploy action is BuildArtifact.

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/file-reference.html#file-reference-ecs-bluegreen
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/file-reference.html#pipelines-create-image-definitions

Comment: Nicely described and it works. One a side note, "apt-get install jq -y" may not be required as "jq" is already available

Answer (score 2):

following aws documentation, you can also do it like this in your buildspec:

```
printf '[{"name":"container_name","imageUri":"image_URI"}]' > imagedefinitions.json
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/file-reference.html

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion. much easier and solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

You get this issue when you have an invalid `json` or it has errors, so you can use a `json` formatter to inspect or copy the `buildspec.yml` file from Google.

Under build spec artifacts, we need have this statement and it sends to S3 bucket. And container name should match with your container name to work. Also image url should have the correct CER repo link and tag (use "latest" mostly)

```
printf '[{"name":"container_name","imageUri":"image_URI"}]' > imagedefinitions.json
```

Then it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment but to expand on the answer from @shariqmaws. This assumes your container is built and pushed to ECR by an external process, and the pipeline only pulls the container and deploys into ECS.

1. Create a CodeBuild Project, and use the code below in the 'Buildspec" section, "Insert build commands". This is slightly edited from the above and works as of March 2024.

**NOTE**: Make sure to update the 'ContainerName' variable as per your environment. Also, the IAM role used by CodeBuild needs to have access to your CodePipeline S3 bucket.

```
version: 0.2
phases:
    build:
        commands:
            - ContainerName="container-name"
            - ImageURI=$(cat imageDetail.json | jq -r '.ImageURI')
            - printf '[{"name":"CONTAINER_NAME","imageUri":"IMAGE_URI"}]' > imagedefinitions.json
            - sed -i -e "s|CONTAINER_NAME|$ContainerName|g" imagedefinitions.json
            - sed -i -e "s|IMAGE_URI|$ImageURI|g" imagedefinitions.json
            - cat imagedefinitions.json

artifacts:
    files:
        - imagedefinitions.json
```

2. Update CodePipeline

Add a build stage, using the CodeBuild project above, under the source stage. The input for the build action is the source action output.

Update the deployment stage to use the build action output as it's input.